# 質問をクローズするまでの投票ロジックの改善案

Tags: 機能の要求

現状だと質問に対して5人のユーザからクローズ票を入れられた時点で「改善待ち」になるかと思いますが、「この質問内容でも問題無い」と思った人が反対票で**クローズ票を打ち消す**ようには出来ないでしょうか。

レビュアーがクローズ票を入れる場合はもちろん慎重に行うべきですが、知識や考え方は人それぞれなので判断が絶対に正しいとは限りません。質問の意図が正しく伝わらないまま誤解などによるクローズ票が入っていた場合に、票を入れたユーザが「票の取り消し」を行わない限り止める術が現状ない気がします(マイナスを入れた側の意見で一方的に結果が決まってしまう)。

質問/回答に対してのUp Vote/Down Voteの様に、プラス評価も加味して結果を決める形に出来ないでしょうか。

Comment: クローズ票の打ち消しということだと、レビューキューにある`オープンのままにする`がソレだと思いますが、そういうことではないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

### 現状存在する機能

ご提案のものとは異なりますが、現状でもクローズに反対する機構自体は存在します。**「オープンのままにする」ボタン**です。

[クローズ票を投じることのできるユーザー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)であれば、他のユーザーがクローズ票を投じたもののまだクローズされていない質問一覧を、クローズ票のレビュー・キューから確認することができます。この画面において「オープンのままにする」ボタンを押すと、クローズに反対することができます。

[image: クローズ票のレビュー・キューです。「クローズ」ボタンの他に「オープンのままにする」ボタンが存在します。]

ただし「オープンのままにする」ボタンの挙動は今回提案されたものとは異なります。一定数のユーザーが「オープンのままにする」ボタンを押すと、その質問がクローズ票のレビュー・キューに表示されなくなります (クローズ票自体は有効期間が終わるまではそのまま残るはずです [要検証])。

また、クローズ票が投じられた質問のクローズに反対する場合、**コメント**にその建設的な理由を残すこともできます。

### 私の意見

これらの機能に加え、クローズ票の数を打ち消せるような「反クローズ票」を実装するのには反対です。

というのも、もし「反クローズ票」が実装されると、特に賛成派の数と否定派の数が拮抗している場合において議論なしに投票ばかり行われ、水面下で投票戦争が起きそうだからです。そうなるよりかは、疑問に思ったユーザーが一定数いた時点で一度議論の俎上に載せ、メタサイトで合意形成してからクローズ／オープンを決める方が健全に思えます。

### 参考

- [How about a “Vote not to close” option to counter the “Vote to close”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/341401) -- Meta Stack Exchange

  - 特に、[Shog9 さんの回答](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134673/341401)が建設的だと感じました。

Comment: 質問本文にも書きましたが質問の意図をうまくくみ取れずにクローズ票を入れているケースも考えられるので、「オープンのままにする」ボタンを押す際に(ポジティブな)判断の助けとなるコメントを残すことを促すようなメッセージが何かあると良いのかなと思いました。

Comment: @cubick さん、面白いアイディアだと思うので、別途回答として投稿してみて頂けませんでしょうか？